# Dojo Databinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, dojo

I have a web application build using **Dojo UI** when the application loads i call `parser.parse()` to create the widgets necessary. I am now attempting to do **data binding** from an **Ajax** request to the **UI**. I have been looking at an example [here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mvc#data-binding-api) however i am seeing the model is set before the parser.

I need to be able to set the model from within a function and bind it to the **UI**.
Since i am calling the parser.parse() a second time i am getting the following error:

```
dojo/parser::parse() error
Error: Tried to register widget with id==xxxx but that id is already registered
```

Also is there a way i can only parse for the bindData function only and avoid this error ?

**Function to preform binding**

```
var model;

function bindData(data){    
    require([       
        "dojo/Stateful",
        "dojo/parser"   


    ], function( Stateful, parser){     
        model = new Stateful(data); 

parser.parse();    
    });
}
```

**Function called when query button is executed**

```
if (getSelectedRadioButton('userOption') == 1){

      if (!dijit.byId("employeeNumberId").value){         
          var employeeNumberId = dijit.byId("employeeNumberId");
          dijit.showTooltip(
            employeeNumberId.get('missingMessage'),
            employeeNumberId.domNode
          );
          showNotificationDialog("okResponseNotificationDialog", 'Please Enter A Valid Employee Number Proceed', 'User Options');
          return false;

      }else{
          showNotificationDialog("okResponseNotificationDialog", 'Please Wait While We Retrive Your Data', 'User Options');

          dojo.xhrPost({
              url: getEmployeeData,
              postData: dojo.toJson({
                employeeNumber: EmployeeId
              }),
              handleAs: "text",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
              },
              sync: true,
              load: function (data) {

                  data = ({First: "John", Last: "Doe", Email: "jdoe@example.com"});

                  bindData(data);                 

              },
              error: function (error) {

                  showNotificationDialog('okResponseNotificationDialog', 'Contact Your HELP DESK  : ' + error, 'Error');
                }

              });         
      }
  }
```

**JSP**

```
<s:textfield required="true" name="Employee.firstname"
  id="surname" placeholder="Your Firstname"
  trim="true"
  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
  missingMessage="Please Enter Your Firstname!"
  invalidMessage="Invalid Firstname!" title="(a) Firstname:"
  style="width: 20em;" data-dojo-props="value: at(model, 'First.name'), uppercase:true, regExp:'^[`a-zA-Z ]+(([\,\.-][`a-zA-Z ])?[`a-zA-Z ]*)*$'"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right you can not call parser.parse() twice.  You probably should use an EditModelRefController instead of just using a Stateful for the model, and then you should be able to set it up originally with dummy data, and then replace it with the real data when it is available.  To see an example of replacing the model, you can look here:
https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/mvc/tests/test_mvc_new-data-replace-simple.html

Comment: I realized i needed to setup a dummy model and later on set its properties using a setter

Comment: can you assist with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564146/dojo-dgrid-databinding